# Abstract (QFBV) bit vector theory to linear arithmetric (LIA)

Tags: z3, smt

My current project involves counting/approximating the number of models in a set of constraints expressed in bit vector arithmetic. The model space is usually very large so enumerative methods will not scale very well. For instance:

```
A = BitVec('A', 32)
B = BitVec('B', 32)
solver.add(A>B)
```

The solution space would be 0.5 * 2 ** (2 * 32), beyond the reach of conventional probabilistic and enumerative models. There are existing tools, that I was hoping to use, such as http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00142.pdf, but it only works for LIA.

I was wondering if there are existing methods, or APIs that allows for such as abstraction. Otherwise the other option  appears to be to manually translate all the clauses into LIA (linear integer arithmetic).

Comment: if your constraints are in LIA, then why don't you just use LIA? if your constraints are not linear, AFAIK, there is no way to convert from a non-linear constraint to a linear one.

Comment: You may also consider converting QFBV into a SAT formula. There are several counting tools for SAT, both precise counting and approximate counting.

Comment: thanks for pointers. I am not aware of any methods to express bitwise operations such as XOR, AND, OR in linear arithmetic.